# Why is my debugger showing wrong outputs in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm a beginner writing in Javascript. This code is an exercise for my university, which has an online testing debugger of some sort that changes the inputs and tests if your code works correctly and what i wrote does. Its used for exams aswell, but I need to know the answers before putting my code into their system, so i dont make a mistake. I'm taught to use the debugger, but im getting wrong outputs when I use it.

The output I get is:
Somewhere in Bulgaria
undefined - 0.00

The output i should be getting is:
Somewhere in Bulgaria
Camp - 15.00

undefined is "holidayType" and 0.00 is "price"
The code is this:

```js
function nestedConditionals(input) {

    let budget = Number(input[0]);
    let season = input[1];

    let price = 0;
    let holidayDestination;
    let holidayType;


    if (budget <= 100) {
        switch (season) {
            case "summer":
                price = budget * 0.30;
                holidayType = "Camp"
                break;
            case "winter":
                price = budget * 0.70;
                holidayType = "Hotel"
                break;
        }

        holidayDestination = "Bulgaria"

    } else if (budget <= 1000) {
        switch (season) {
            case "summer":
                price = budget * 0.40;
                holidayType = "Camp"
                break;
            case "winter":
                price = budget * 0.80;
                holidayType = "Hotel"
                break;
        }

        holidayDestination = "Balkans"

    } else if (budget > 1000) {

        holidayType = "Hotel";
        price = budget * 0.90;
        holidayDestination = "Europe"

    }

    console.log(`Somewhere in ${holidayDestination}`)
    console.log(`${holidayType} - ${price.toFixed(2)}`)

}

nestedConditionals("50", "summer")
```

Comment: The problem is that you're calling your function with two arguments - `nestedConditionals("50", "summer")`, whereas your code expects a single array argument `function nestedConditionals(input)`. Do you understand how to fix that?

Comment: @fubar No, i dont know how to fix that. My teachers code is the exact same way and the debugger seems to give him the correct outputs, not sure why its different for me. Edit: I've figured it out, I missed the [ ]. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your function `nestedConditionals(input)` has an arity of 1, it means that it is waiting for only one argument where 2 were given in your example **("50", "summer")**.

What you can do to fix that is to call your function with one argument of type *Array* like `nestedContidionals(["50", "summer"])`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function nestedConditionals(input) {

    let budget = Number(input[0]);
    let season = input[1];

    let price = 0;
    let holidayDestination;
    let holidayType;


    if (budget <= 100) {
        switch (season) {
            case "summer":
                price = budget * 0.30;
                holidayType = "Camp"
                break;
            case "winter":
                price = budget * 0.70;
                holidayType = "Hotel"
                break;
        }

        holidayDestination = "Bulgaria"

    } else if (budget <= 1000) {
        switch (season) {
            case "summer":
                price = budget * 0.40;
                holidayType = "Camp"
                break;
            case "winter":
                price = budget * 0.80;
                holidayType = "Hotel"
                break;
        }

        holidayDestination = "Balkans"

    } else if (budget > 1000) {

        holidayType = "Hotel";
        price = budget * 0.90;
        holidayDestination = "Europe"

    }

    console.log(`Somewhere in ${holidayDestination}`)
    console.log(`${holidayType} - ${price.toFixed(2)}`)

}

nestedConditionals(["50", "summer"])
```

```js
function nestedConditionals(input) {

    let budget = Number(input[0]);
    let season = input[1];

    let price = 0;
    let holidayDestination;
    let holidayType;


    if (budget <= 100) {
        switch (season) {
            case "summer":
                price = budget * 0.30;
                holidayType = "Camp"
                break;
            case "winter":
                price = budget * 0.70;
                holidayType = "Hotel"
                break;
        }

        holidayDestination = "Bulgaria"

    } else if (budget <= 1000) {
        switch (season) {
            case "summer":
                price = budget * 0.40;
                holidayType = "Camp"
                break;
            case "winter":
                price = budget * 0.80;
                holidayType = "Hotel"
                break;
        }

        holidayDestination = "Balkans"

    } else if (budget > 1000) {

        holidayType = "Hotel";
        price = budget * 0.90;
        holidayDestination = "Europe"

    }

    console.log(`Somewhere in ${holidayDestination}`)
    console.log(`${holidayType} - ${price.toFixed(2)}`)

}

nestedConditionals("50", "summer")
```

Comment: you have use like array value.